# Java simple paint code not working

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent, mouse-listeners

I have this simple paint code that should draw but instead it moves the **oval** around the panel.
When I remove `super.paintComponent(g)` line the program works it paints and not just move the oval, but I keep reading that we should not remove this line, so what can I do to leave the line in but still get the desired results?

```
class OraclePaint extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OraclePaint ss = new OraclePaint();
        ss.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ss.add(new MyPanel());
        ss.setSize(250, 200);
        ss.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private int x = -10, y = -10;

    public MyPanel() {
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();
                repaint();
            }
        }); // end call to addMouseMotionListener
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 22, 22);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try positive values for `x` and `y` coordinates.

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work.

Comment: It moves it around because you ask it to paint it every time the mouse  is dragged. Sure you dont want mouseclicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the description, I assume that you want something like "a simple paint program".

It is correct to invoke `super.paintComponent(g)` as the first line of an overridden `paintComponent`. And it is true that this erases the background (that is, everything that was painted before will be deleted).

In Swing, *everything* that you want to paint has to be painted in the `paintComponent` method (or in any method that is called from there, and receives the same `Graphics` object).

If you want to "save" everything that you have painted, you have to paint everything into an image (that is, into a `BufferedImage`), and paint this image in your `paintComponent` method.

There are some other issues with the code, but without changing too much of the remaining code, this could roughly (!) be achieved like this:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class OraclePaint extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OraclePaint ss = new OraclePaint();
        ss.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ss.add(new MyPanel());
        ss.setSize(250, 200);
        ss.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage image = null;

    public MyPanel() {
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
                if (image != null) {

                    // Paint into the image
                    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
                    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g.fillOval(event.getX(),  event.getY(), 22, 22);
                    g.dispose();

                    repaint();
                }
            }
        }); // end call to addMouseMotionListener
    }

    // Make sure that the image is not 'null' and that
    // it has the same size as this panel
    private void validateImage()
    {
        if (image == null)
        {
            image = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(),
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        }
        if (image.getWidth() != getWidth() || image.getHeight() != getHeight())
        {
            BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(),
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics g = newImage.getGraphics();
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            g.dispose();
            image = newImage;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        validateImage();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your `MyPanel` to this:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel
{
    private int x2 = 0, y2 = 0;
    private int x1 = 0, y1 = 0;
    public MyPanel()
    {
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter()
        {
            public void mouseDragged( MouseEvent event )
            {
                x2 = event.getX();
                y2 = event.getY();
                repaint();
            }
        }
        ); // end call to addMouseMotionListener

        addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                x1 = e.getX();
                y1 = e.getY();
            }
        });

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillOval(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
}
```